# server closed the connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I am using sqlalchemy(`sqlalchemy==1.4.6`) to do a query, the database is PostgreSQL 13, this is my Python 3 code look like:

```
def select_channel_by_id(self, channel_id):
    with session_scope() as local_session:
        rss = None
        try:
            rss = local_session.query(RssSource).filter(RssSource.id == channel_id).one()
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            local_session.rollback()
            logger.error("query rss source by id error", e)
        finally:
            local_session.close()
        return rss
```

when I run to this code, shows error like this:

```
[2021-10-25 18:42:00,040: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 731, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

[2021-10-25 18:42:00,040: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3]   File "/root/pydolphin/dolphin/tasks/tasks.py", line 33, in pull_channel_impl
    source = rss.select_channel_by_id(channel_id)

[2021-10-25 18:42:00,040: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3]   File "/root/pydolphin/dolphin/common/db/rss_source.py", line 61, in select_channel_by_id
    logger.error("query rss source by id error", e)

[2021-10-25 18:42:00,040: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Message: 'query rss source by id error'
Arguments: (OperationalError('(psycopg2.OperationalError) server closed the connection unexpectedly\n\tThis probably means the server terminated abnormally\n\tbefore or while processing the request.\n'),)
```

why would this happen? what should I do to fix this problem? BTW, this is my session scope look like:

```
@contextmanager
def session_scope():
    scope_session = Session()
    try:
        yield scope_session
        scope_session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        scope_session.rollback()
        logger.error("session management error", e)
    finally:
        scope_session.close()
```

this is my PostgreSQL(deploy in kubernetes cluster) log look like:

```
2021-10-25 11:03:34.794 GMT [29779] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.562 GMT [29800] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.563 GMT [29801] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.565 GMT [29799] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.566 GMT [29796] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.568 GMT [29795] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.569 GMT [29798] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.571 GMT [29794] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2021-10-25 11:04:07.572 GMT [29797] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: I'd check your postgresql logs.

Comment: That looks like both end thinks the other end is closing the connection. Is there anything else in your setup that might be interfering? I'd try temporarily turning off all firewalls you have on both VMs/containers and on the virtual network. But this is starting to look like an infrastructure problem.

Comment: This error sometimes throw, sometimes works fine. I did not figure out how to find the problem and fix it. I check the session and found 90% session are idle.@Rup

Comment: If it's just idle connections timing out then you probably want to detect this error and retry the search once if you get it. However I'd have expected the Python postgresql driver to have managed that itself.

Comment: That looks like you need to set the "keepalive" PostgreSQL parameters to prevent your firewall or router from closing idle connections.

Answer (score 1):

***Your firewall might be closing the Postgres connection.***

#### Here is how you prevent such occurrence on Windows:

Go to **Control Panel** -> **Systems and Security** ->  **Windows Firewall** -> **Advanced Settings** -> **Inbound Rules** -> **New Rule** under the actions tab (top left)

Then select the following:

- Rule Type: **Port** *(click Next)*
- TCP or UDP: **TCP** *(click Next)*
- Specific local ports: **5432** *(click Next)*
- Action: **Allow the connection** *(click Next)*
- When does this rule apply: **Domain**, **Private** and **Public** (all three
  checked) *(click Next)*
- Name: "**PostgreSQL Incoming**" *(click Next)*

Any firewall exception will take effect as soon as saved. Test the connection again.